# anjularjs push value to nested ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have an ng-repeat nested within another ng-repeat. I want to push some values to the second array when the button is clicked

```
<div ng-repeat="vehicle in vehicleList">
  <div>{{vehicle.number}}</div>
  <input name="addName" value="add" ng-click="addVehicle(vehicle)"
  <div ng-repeat="categoryList in vehicle.category">
    <div>{{categoryList.name}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

```
I tried following code but it's not working
$scope.vehicleList=[];

$scope.addVehicle = function(){
 $scope.vehicleList.push({
   category:'car'
 });
}
```

Can anyone help me on this. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div ng-repeat="vehicle in vehicleList">
  <div>{{vehicle.number}}</div>
  <input name="addName" value="add" ng-click="addVehicle($index, vehicle)">
  <div ng-repeat="categoryList in vehicle.category">
    <div>{{categoryList.name}}</div>
  </div>
</div>

$scope.vehicleList = [];

$scope.addVehicle = function(index, vehicle) {
 $scope.vehicleList[index].category.push({
   name: vehicle
 });
};
```