# How to push items in a nested array with AngularJs

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-resource

I'm looking for two things:

- To push items in a nested array with Angularjs
- To understand how it works exactly.

I've been looking for answers on differents [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21422510/anjularjs-push-value-to-nested-ng-repeat) topic but I didn't manage to come to a solution.

Actually, I want to use an Add Item button to push an **item** in a **items array** under a **facture object**.

Here is my controller:

```
PlasmaCrm.controller('FacturesSoloController', function($scope, $stateParams, Facture ) {

   Facture.get({ id: $stateParams.factureId }, function(data) {
       $scope.facture = data;
   });

   $scope.ajouterItem = function(index, item){
    $scope.facture.items[index].item.push({
      description: 'Test'
    });
   }

});
```

And here is my data structure (as returned by my API)

```
  {
     "id":10200,
     "client_id":1,
     "lead_id":1,
     "courtedescription":"Description test",
     "etat":"En attente",
     "created_at":"2015-02-21 15:07:17",
     "updated_at":"2015-02-21 15:07:17",
     "items":[
        {
           "id":1,
           "facture_id":10200,
           "description":"Item num\u00e9ro 1",
           "prix":"15.00",
           "tps":"0.75",
           "tvq":"1.50",
           "grandtotal":"17.25",
           "created_at":"2015-02-21 15:07:18",
           "updated_at":"2015-02-21 15:07:18"
        },
        {
           "id":2,
           "facture_id":10200,
           "description":"Deuxi\u00e8me item quoi",
           "prix":"135.00",
           "tps":"6.75",
           "tvq":"13.47",
           "grandtotal":"155.22",
           "created_at":"2015-02-21 15:07:18",
           "updated_at":"2015-02-21 15:07:18"
        }
     ]
  }
```

Of course my HTML contains a button:

```
<form ng-submit="ajouterItem(item)">
   <button class="btn btn-primary">Ajouter un item</button>
</form>
```

Actually I got an error (undefined) when I press to button. What is wrong?

Comment: Interesting that your `ng-submit` passes in a single param, but your function expects (and attempts to use) both an `index` and an `item`.  Perhaps `item` is what's undefined?

Comment: I got Cannot read property 'items' of undefined

Answer (score 2):

For those who are still looking for pushing data in the nested array can refer below example of **Comments and Replies** :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>


    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

        <!--Comment section-->
        <ul ng-repeat="comment in comments track by $index" style="background: skyblue; padding: 10px;">
            <li>
                <b>Comment {{$index}} : </b>
                <br>
                {{comment.comment}}
                <!--Reply section-->
                    <ul ng-repeat="reply in comment.reply track by $index">
                        <li><i>Reply {{$index}} :</i><br>
                            {{reply.comment}}</li>
                    </ul>
                <!--End reply section-->
                <input type="text" ng-model="reply" placeholder=" Write your reply." /><a href="" ng-click="insertReply($index,reply)">Reply</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <!--End comment section -->
            

        <!--Post your comment-->
        <b>New comment</b>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Your comment" ng-model="comment" />
        <a href="" ng-click="newComment(comment)">Post </a>
    </div>


    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {

            //Comments object having reply oject
            $scope.comments = [{ comment: 'hi', reply: [{ comment: 'hi inside commnet' }, { comment: 'hi inside commnet' }] }];

            //push reply
            $scope.insertReply = function (index, reply) {
                $scope.comments[index].reply.push({ comment: reply });
            }

            //push commnet
            $scope.newComment = function (comment) {
                $scope.comments.push({ comment: comment, reply: [] });
            }
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no item property inside the items array objects, you cant push to it. You have to add:

```
$scope.facture.items[index].item = []
```

before you can push to it. Also check your functions parameters as Marc states in his comment. Since we can't see all of the markup it is unclear what is passed to the function, a simple console.log() will show you that ofcourse.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, it was finaly simpler than I first thought:

```
$scope.ajouterItem = function(){
    $scope.facture.items.push({
      description: 'Test'
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, create a variable to fill, delete, and add items. Next, assign this variable to the array inside the model.

```
PlasmaCrm.controller('FacturesSoloController', function($scope, $stateParams, Facture ) 
{
    $scope.items= [];

    Facture.get({ id: $stateParams.factureId }, function(data) {
       $scope.facture = data;
       $scope.items = $scope.facture.items;
    });

    $scope.ajouterItem = function(item){
        $scope.items.push(item);
        $scope.facture.Items = $scope.items;
    }

});
```

In this way, you can also edit the previous information and add new information. Since we first set "items". To remove the same as usual :

```
$scope.RemoveItem = function (index) {
    $scope.facture.Items.splice(index, 1);
};
```